# Create installation package for a program that uses IIS and SQL Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, iis-6, windows-installer, sql-server-express

I have an application that was developed in Visual Studio 2008 using ASP.NET. Part of it is a website that uses IIS 6 and accesses a database in SQL Express 2008 and the other part is a standalone application that allows users to add information to the database. Is it possible to create an installation package that clients could use to install everything themselves without purchasing some expensive program like InstallAware or InstallSheild? Can this be done within Visual Studio?

The goal is to have SQL Express and IIS (and of course .NET) bundled with the application so that all necessary technology is set up upon install.

Comment: Setting up IIS during an install of another app has some dangerous implications, as it opens up several ports to incoming requests, etc.  This should generally only be done on dev systems and servers... are you sure this is what your customers want?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors Good point. This application would just be installed on dedicated servers.

Comment: You can try using WiX: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: in that case, you ought to be able to count on most places with a dedicated server to have someone competent to make sure IIS is setup _and secured_ on that server. Unless they have someone who can do the latter (which implies the former), they are just asking to get hacked. This has nothing to do with your product and everything to do with the general nature of running a web site. In other words, it's perfectly okay and even expected that IIS be listed as a prerequisite for a server product. I would consider it irresponsible and be concerned about a vendor that did otherwise.

Comment: @Joel - Thanks, Joel. That was helpful. You're right. I might reconsider including IIS.

@Cosmin - Thanks! I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet would be to use a combination of WiX and the Setup Project that comes built in with Visual Studio. It's not that robust, but you can do most of the database stuff with custom actions and WiX has some IIS support.